# I can't connect to AWS RDS from Terminal with MAC OS X Catalina

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, rds, terminal

I've been taking a course from Udemy on AWS and I am trying to connect to RDS using an instance. I've installed MySQL and am running MySQL Workbench. I'm trying to access my instance using terminal commands in Mac OS X Catalina. I'm using the command:

```
mysql> \connect admin@backspace-intro2-aws.c7doukhhpptr.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com;
```

Is this the correct command?

I get the error:

```
No connection. Trying to reconnect...
ERROR 1059 (42000): Identifier name ' admin@backspace-intro2-aws.c7doukhhpptr.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com' is too long
ERROR: Can't connect to the server
```

I've tried adjusting the security permissions and changed the TCP/IP but still no luck.

Comment: Is that more than 64 characters?

Answer (score 1):

I spent a while trying to figure this out, but with the help of another computer savvy friend, you-tube videos, and a lot of trial and error I learned that I could access my RDS on AWS with the following command in terminal from zsh shell:

```
/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql -u admin -p -h (*insert db endpoint here*);
```

It was not a question of whether the string was more than 64 characters.